# How to call WFS from a WPS in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t, wps

I have a custom WPS process, and from that, I need to call WFS to insert Transaction request, because I don't want to make two requests. I tried looking into GeoServer transaction test code but was not able to figure out the way to make the request.

Comment: I don't think you can, are there any existing processes that let you do that?